# HTML5 pattern - 10 characters - at least one letter

Tags: html, regex, validation

I need to make HTML5 validation rule so:

- 10 characters
- mix of letters and numbers
- at least 1 letter

I try something like:

```
<input maxlength="200" type="text" name="serial" id="serial" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" pattern="[a-fA-F]{1,}[0-9]{10}" title="Wrong Code" placeholder="Security Code" />
```

but don't work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `<input type="password" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,10}$" required>`

Or this (it's a bit longer...):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <style>
  input {
   width: 100%;
   padding: 12px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 4px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin-top: 6px;
   margin-bottom: 16px
  }
  input[type=button] {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white
  }
  .container {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   padding: 20px
  }
  #message {
   display: none;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 10px
  }
  .valid {
   display: none
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form action="/db.php" id="form">
   <label for="psw">Password</label>
   <input type="password" id="psw" name="psw" required>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="analyze()">
  </form>
 </div>
 <div id="message">
  <h3 id="theH3">Your password doesn't contain any of the following:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">A letter</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">A number</p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">10 characters</p>
 </div>
  <script>
    var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
  var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
  var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
  var number = document.getElementById("number");
  var length = document.getElementById("length");
    var tmp = 0;
  myInput.onfocus = function () {
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
  }
  myInput.onblur = function () {
   document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
  }
  myInput.onkeyup = function () {
   var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
   if (myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
        tmp++;
   } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
   }
   var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
   if (myInput.value.match(numbers)) {
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
        tmp++;
   } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
   } if (myInput.value.length >= 10) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
        tmp++;
   } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
   }
  }
    function analyze() {
    var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
    var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
    if (lowerCaseLetters.test(myInput.value) && numbers.test(myInput.value))document.getElementById('form').submit();
        if(tmp==3){
        var message = document.getElementById('theH3')
        message.style('display:none;');
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, JUST in code is not important lower or uppercase - important is to be a letter ... please update

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: thanks, this works well but what if user type 12345689A - then input is not valid, and should be valid 123456789a and 123456789A also

Answer (score 3):

```html
<input maxlength="200" type="text" name="serial" id="serial" required="required" class="form-control input-lg" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,10}$" title="Wrong Code" placeholder="Security Code" />
```

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,10}$
```

I think you are looking for this [website](http://html5pattern.com/Names).
URL : http://html5pattern.com/Names

Comment: pattern you post dont work ... so I need to submit only if input field contain 10 characters - mix of letters and numbers - at least one letter

Answer (score 1):

just add the word *required* at the end

```html
<input maxlength="200" type="text" name="serial" id="serial" class="form-control input-lg" pattern="[a-fA-F]{1,}[0-9]{10}" title="Wrong Code" placeholder="Security Code" required>
```